# Many-to-Many MySQl PHP

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I am trying to create a link table in mySQL to manage the association of products and skus.  An example, the product is a t-shirt.  The sku is each t-shirt's size and color combination.  I want to handle products and skus many-to-many relationships because we sell items and bulk.  Bulk products may be comprised of individual skus.  Ergo, one sku could be associated with many products.

So, I am pretty sure I need products and skus to have a many-to-many relationship.   What I don't understand though is how to poulate the Link table.  In other words, when I create a product I generate a productid in the product table.  When I create the sku I have a skuid in the sku table.   How to I take the productid and skuid (each primary keys in the thier own table) and add them to the link table.  Each skuID and productID pair should be unique so I would like those two fields to serve as my primary key.

Anyway, when I try to create the relationship in phpmyadmin using the designer I get "Error: relation not added".

Comment: Which storage engine do you use? Do you have foreign key constraints? Do you have some code to show? Some SQL statements?

Comment: If your populating it through PHP just store the ID values in variables and add a new entry to a new table referencing those ID values. You don't need an explicit relationship in phpMyAdmin - you could mock it up.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you are trying to link 2 tables 1 for t-shirt product and 2 thsirt size and color, for table 1 make a product id which is primary and for table 2 create a product id field similar to table 1 which will link your two tables the only difference is that in table 2 product id is not your primary key